# Burninate [smooth]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I think the [smooth](/questions/tagged/smooth) tag (with 274 questions) needs to be burninated. There are so many things it could mean:

- [smooth animation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17739964/1223693)
- [smooth data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17738746/1223693) (as in remove noise)
- [smooth sound](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17640742/1223693)
- [smooth transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17635931/1223693)
- [smooth scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17631417/1223693)
- [antialiasing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17564883/1223693) ("smooth line")
- [gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17420016/1223693) ("smooth colors")
- [a smoother](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17418480/1223693) (which is a term in chart drawing)

These were **the 8 most recent questions** with this tag. Eight questions with the [smooth](/questions/tagged/smooth) tag, and *none of them even mean the same thing?!* This tag is *much* too vague and I don't think it should exist.

Burninate?

[image: Burninate!]

Comment: Do note that we do have [tag:smooth-scrolling], [tag:font-smoothing], [tag:smooth-streaming], and [tag:smooth-numbers] tags. Before burnination, some of those questions should be manually retagged to use a more appropriate tag.

Comment: Yes, when I think of smooth, I think of a guy with a cocktail, chatting me up ;)